# Automatic Spotipy Max Retries Reached

Tags: python, webapi, spotipy

I am trying to retrieve audio_features from all my songs (5985) in batches of 100 songs using Spotipy.  A simpler version of the code I used without the exception handling worked fine for all the first 1416 items, then it is now completely blocked. I then tried to solve it by using the code below:

```
def exponential_backoff_retry(func, *args, max_retries=3, base_delay=1, **kwargs):
    for attempt in range(max_retries):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except SpotifyException as e:
            if e.http_status == 429:
                print(f"Rate limited. Retrying in {base_delay * 2 ** attempt} seconds.")
                time.sleep(base_delay * 2 ** attempt)
            else:
                raise e
    print("Max retries exceeded. Unable to fetch track features.")
    return None


def get_user_saved_track_features(sp, ids, start_track_id=None, batch_size=100):
    tracks = []

    # Iterate through each batch of track IDs
    batches = [ids[i:i+batch_size] for i in range(start_track_id or 0, len(ids), batch_size)]
    for batch in batches:
        for track_id in batch:
            meta = exponential_backoff_retry(sp.track, track_id)
            name = meta['name']
            album = meta['album']['name']
            artist = meta['album']['artists'][0]['name']
            release_date = meta['album']['release_date']
            length = meta['duration_ms']
            popularity = meta['popularity']
            print(f"Processed meta for track ID {track_id}")
        
        print(f"Processed all metatracks")

        batch_features = exponential_backoff_retry(sp.audio_features, batch)

        if batch_features:
            for features in batch_features:
                if features and features[0]:
                    print(f"Processing features {track_id}")
                    acousticness = features['acousticness']
                    danceability = features['danceability']
                    energy = features['energy']
                    instrumentalness = features['instrumentalness']
                    liveness = features['liveness']
                    loudness = features['loudness']
                    speechiness = features['speechiness']
                    tempo = features['tempo']
                    valence = features['valence']
                    time_signature = features['time_signature']
                    key = features['key']
                    mode = features['mode']
                    uri = features['uri']

                    tracks.append([name, album, artist, release_date, length, popularity,
                                   acousticness, danceability, energy, instrumentalness,
                                   liveness, loudness, speechiness, tempo, valence,
                                   time_signature, key, mode, uri])
                    print(f"Processed track ID audio features {track_id}")
                else:
                    print(f"Skipping track ID {track_id} because at least one feature value is None")

                time.sleep(1)  # Sleep for 1 second per song
        elif batch_features is None:
            print(f"Skipping batch due to error")

        time.sleep(1) # Sleep for 1 second per batch to avoid rate limiting
            
    # Create DataFrame from the list of track features
    df = pd.DataFrame(tracks, columns=['name', 'album', 'artist', 'release_date',
                                       'length', 'popularity', 'acousticness', 'danceability',
                                       'energy', 'instrumentalness', 'liveness', 'loudness',
                                       'speechiness', 'tempo', 'valence', 'time_signature',
                                       'key', 'mode', 'uri'])

    return df
```

Weirdly, the requests are accepted every time for this part:

```
        for track_id in batch:
            meta = exponential_backoff_retry(sp.track, track_id)
            name = meta['name']
            album = meta['album']['name']
            artist = meta['album']['artists'][0]['name']
            release_date = meta['album']['release_date']
            length = meta['duration_ms']
            popularity = meta['popularity']
            print(f"Processed meta for track ID {track_id}")
```

But from `batch_features = exponential_backoff_retry(sp.audio_features, batch)`, the 'Max Retries Reached' error is automatically caught from the first batch and even the first feature.

I also tried changing the `start_id` but no success.

Comment: what is the actual error message that is being returned ?

Comment: @D.L the error I tried to handle is:
`spotipy.exceptions.SpotifyException: http status: 429, code:-1 - /v1/audio-features/?ids=4TTV7EcfroSLWzXRY6gLv6:
Max Retries, reason: too many 429 error responses`

Comment: A 429 error response is a status code in the HTTP protocol indicating that the user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting"). It's typically used by web servers to prevent abuse and ensure fair usage of resources.

Answer (score 0):

according to the error message that you poster, the (code is 429) error response is a status code in the HTTP protocol indicating that **the user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting")**. It's typically used by web servers to prevent abuse and ensure fair usage of resources.

Basically, you can:

1. check the site for limits and adhere to those.
2. empirically make fewer requests until it becomes acceptable.

it is probably better to understand the limits.

BTW: rate limiting is quite common.